# Trying to resolve .local to 127.0.0.1 using dnsmasq and Network Manager

Tags: apache2, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to develop php projects locally. What I want is to be able to mass virtual host local projects and when I create a project and add the `.local` to the project name, always have resolve to 127.0.0.1. What I have tried so far:

1. Disable and Stop `systemd-resolved`.

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
   sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
   ```
2. Remove symlinked `resolv.conf`

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Created a new `resolv.conf` file in `/etc/` and added `nameserver 8.8.8.8`
4. Installed `dnsmasq`
5. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` I have the following:

   ```
   [main]
   dns=dnsmasq
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

   [ifupdown]
   managed=false

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```
6. In `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` I have created a `local.conf` file which has:

   ```
   address=/local/127.0.0.1
   ```
7. Reload Network manager, but every time I do this it resets my `resolv.conf` to be `127.0.1.1` so I have to reset the nameserver to be `8.8.8.8`.

Output `sudo netstat -anlp | grep 53`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39737/dnsmasq       
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      39737/dnsmasq       
tcp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::53030 2606:4700::6810:5f4:443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
tcp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::53936 2a04:fa87:fffe::c00:443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
tcp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::57530 2600:1f1c:a99:832c::443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           39737/dnsmasq       
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           4759/chrome         
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           4802/chrome --type= 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1109/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                39737/dnsmasq       
udp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::35397 2607:f8b0:4007:803::443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
udp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::53965 2607:f8b0:400e:c09::443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1109/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 2600:8800:86ac:2::38534 2607:f8b0:4007:80f::443 ESTABLISHED 4802/chrome --type= 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     75311    3037/Xorg            @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     75312    3037/Xorg            /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40653    1386/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     970535   44951/chrome --type  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21922    531/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     805753   2900/pulseaudio      /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     164653   7749/gdm-session-wo  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     970534   4759/chrome          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     84953    3037/Xorg            @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129536   4952/chrome --type=  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129538   4759/chrome          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129535   4759/chrome          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     81853    3294/ibus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     109534   4073/gnome-terminal  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    21931    531/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     88353    3434/dconf-service   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129539   4957/chrome --type=  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129153   1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     83553    3393/ibus-engine-si  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    21933    531/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     97533    3622/evolution-sour  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     89353    3600/gnome-shell-ca  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    21934    531/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     130853   4759/chrome          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     83353    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132553   4611/update-notifie  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     39532    1903/rtkit-daemon    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100532   2906/dbus-daemon     /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     868534   2900/pulseaudio      /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     35395    1456/kerneloops      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28453    1114/dbus-daemon     /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100653   3660/gsd-media-keys  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     35396    1458/kerneloops      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     93535    3622/evolution-sour  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     708953   4759/chrome          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100530   2906/dbus-daemon     /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     35394    1421/whoopsie        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     968853   1989/master
```

Per Brian Turek I ran dnsmasq, then reloaded NetoworkManager.service then ran `ps aux | grep dnsmasq` and this is the output:

```
nobody    103697  0.0  0.0  14776  4264 ?        S    06:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
paul    103707  0.0  0.0   9028   676 pts/0    S+   06:12   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox dnsmasq
```

Comment: I have no idea how to to do what you want. I know `.local` domain is assigned by the Avahi daemon for devices connected by LAN. For example, if you have a computer in your LAN called `cutiepi` and your home router has assigned the IP address `192.168.0.234`, then typing `cutiepi.local` will take you to `192.168.0.234`. Since Avahi is installed by default in Ubuntu, you may want to look into its settings, disabling, or uninstalling it.

Comment: @user68186 What if I just want to have anything ```.localhost``` resolve instead of ```.local``` then?

Comment: Using `.localhost` will probably avoid any conflicts with Avahi. Feel free to write an answer if you figure it out.

Comment: For sure I am still fiddling with settings to see if I can come up with something. I will post if I figure it out before someone on here presents a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think NetworkManager is behaving as expected.  NetworkManager is presumably starting a DNSmasq instance and setting your machine to use that to resolve DNS address (thus changing /etc/resolv.conf).

I think you want to add `server=8.8.8.8` to your `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local.conf` as well as `no-resolv`.  This should cause DNSmasq to use Google as your upstream DNS and have your machine use DNSmasq as the local resolver.

Comment: my local.conf now has this ```address=/local/127.0.0.1
server=8.8.8.8
no-resolv
``` But when I try to resolve test.local with just an index.php file in it which echo "hi" and go to test.local/ in my browser it still doesn't resolve.

Comment: Also, I ran ```sudo systemctl reload network-manager``` and reloaded dnsmasq, and checked ```/etc/resolv.conf``` and it reset my ```nameserver 127.0.1.1``` and my now I can't load any web pages. I had to manually replace the nameserver with 8.8.8.8 in ```resolv.conf```

Comment: Can do you a `sudo netstat -anlp | grep 53` and still what program(s) are bound on port 53?  Hopefully `systemd-resolved` is not running.

Comment: I just posted the output in my question. I only see ```dnsmasq``` bound to port ```53```

Comment: Ok, my theory is that dnsmasq is starting as its own service rather than being controlled by NetworkManager so it's not getting your config.  Can you do a `systemctl stop dnsmasq` and then reload NetworkManager?  After you do so, can you post the output of `ps aux | grep dnsmasq`?

Comment: I went ahead and posted what you requested.

Comment: So it looks like dnsmasq is running and has the correct config loaded.  Can you try something like `dig google @127.0.0.1`?  This will send a DNS request directly to dnsmasq.

Comment: should I restart dnsmasq and reload NetworkManager and then run the ```dig``` command or should I run the ```dig``` command in the current condition of dnsmasq being stopped/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112526/discussion-between-brian-turek-and-pa-gw).

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, credit goes to Brian Turek. Turns out I had to disable dnsmasq `sudo systemctl stop dnsmaq.service` and then restart systemd resolve since NetworkManager was running it's own instance of dnsmasq. Then to get all of my local projects within my `/home/projects/www/` folder I had to disable all of the current `sites-enabled` sites found within `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. `000.default.conf` was preventing any other sites from loading properly.